# XML Parsing Error: no root element found for Browser upload to S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I am trying to implement a File upload to `S3` via Browser using `signedUrl` method. I am able to successfully upload the file but I get this error in browser.

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: https://x.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/nithin/a4512m6g4cdg14of5h64sl.pdf
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

I am using `axios` to `PUT` the object like this

```
     axios
        .post(
            config.apiUrl +
                config.S3URL +
                "/" +
                (this.props.folderName || "default"),
            {
                filename: getNewFileName(file.name),
                filetype: file.type
            }
        )
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log("Result", result);

            var signedUrl = result.data.signedURL;

            var options = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": file.type
                }
            };

            return axios.put(signedUrl, file, options);
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log("Final", result);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        });
```

I get into the `Final` part but then the error pops up.

Comment: I looks like you are tring to parse a PDF file as XML. Have you tried to remove the log lines?  Maybe the error is from trying to log.

Comment: Oh, When i do the same via Postman i get no response from the server.